# Why does the compiler does not find android.R.id.home constant?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my kotlin project for android, I get an error saying that android.R.id.home is undefined. Meanwhile, I am fixing the minimum android sdk to 14. I am using Kotlin '1.0.1-2'.

Here is an excerpt of the code that needs it (it is an Activity, a plain one, not a AppCompatAcitivity)

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.getItemId()){
        is android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Here is the error :

```
e: $<path_start_from_my_disc>/AboutActivity.kt: (70, 29): Unresolved reference: home
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `is` operator for the equality check, whereas it's a type check operator (like `instanceof`). It should work if you just remove `is`:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.getItemId()){
        android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```